# "Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:..." error when trying to use named outlet

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular8, angular-router

I'm trying to add a `/login` route to my app through a named outlet. All the other routes are within the primary outlet and only the login page is supposed to be in a different outlet. This is my setup for the `/login` route in the `appRoutes` array in `app.module.ts`:

```
{ path: 'login',
  component: LoginComponent,
  data: { title: 'Login' },
  outlet: 'login'
}
```

And in my `app.component.html` template, I have the following:

```
<app-main-nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-main-nav>
<router-outlet name="login"></router-outlet>
```

I'm trying to navigate to the login page directly by typing the URL into the browser, but I'm getting the error `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'`

When I add the login route to the primary outlet it works fine, but then the `<app-main-nav>` is wrapped around it which is exactly the reason why I want to separate this page from the rest and give it its own outlet. I've searched around about this error message but for most people the issue seems to be that the `routerLink` is wrong in their template, but since I'm trying to navigate to this route manually through the URL bar, those solutions don't apply to me. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: please make a stackblitz example  https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this url

http://localhost:4200/(login:login)

This is to specify which router will be taking which route

Comment: Tried it and I'm no longer getting any errors, but the `LoginComponent` isn't being rendered on the page, only the main navbar is there with an empty page below it.

Comment: I'm sorry, the `LoginComponent` **is** actually being rendered on the page, but it was pushed all the way down by the main navbar that is now still rendering with the empty primary `<router-outlet>` inside of it. I can get rid of it with an `*ngIf` that checks if the user is logged in or not, but then I could have done the same with the login component inside the primary outlet, I assume?

Comment: Yes you can that will be good because you don't have to main the url like this and it would be bad